# Can't unscrew metal p-trap nut

Tags: plumbing, bathroom

I am having a major hard time trying to remove this metal P-trap. The nut in the back will not budge no matter how hard I try. I was able to remove the front one relatively easily using some pliers but not the back. Does anyone have any tips on how to remove these metals nuts from old plumbing? Also yes there is water dripping in the back, it's not a leak just a mistake I made haha. Also if I am able to remove this, can I just replace the whole trap with a PVC one? Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, once removed you may use a plastic trap assembly to replace it.

You will need a bigger tool, like a large pipe wrench or large "Channellock" type plier. It won't be easy (upside down headfirst in a cabinet with restricted space) but that's why plumbers are well paid. Try soaking the nut thoroughly with a penetrating oil overnight.

They make offset wrenches for this type of job, but they are expensive. I have never needed one, just a big pipe wrench.

Comment: My only concern with this is causing too much stress on the pipe from the flexing and busting something behind the wall.

Comment: That's a legitimate concern, you should take care to only apply rotational force to the nut. Alternatively you could cut or break the nut off, but be careful not to damage the threads on the 1 1/2" steel pipe coming out of the wall. Soak it and get a bigger wrench, it will come loose.

Comment: This may sound dumb but I am new to this, do you have any suggestion on what to soak it with? Thank you

Comment: WD-40, Liquid Wrench, PB Blaster, or any quality penetrating spray lubricant.